# Firefox, display: -moz-box adds weird margin on top

Tags: html, firefox, css, flexbox

I have a list of 3 block elements which should stack regularly. The second element in the stack is a box element, for which I used the

```
display: -moz-box;
-moz-box-orient: horizontal;
```

The issue is in this box element, as it adds a weird unwanted margin on top of itself. You can check it out at the following link http://jsfiddle.net/frapontillo/ghA5X/.

Correct behavior in Chrome:

[image: Correct behavior in Chrome]

Wrong behavior in Firefox/Aurora:

[image: Wrong behavior in Firefox]

What can cause this? Chrome behaves fine with it, while Firefox (release channel) and Aurora have this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What causes this, at least in part, that `-moz-box` and `-webkit-box` mean totally different things and have totally different behavior.  The former is a XUL box, with behavior dating back over 10 years.  The latter is an implementation of an early CSS flexbox draft from several years ago.

I recommend not using these at all if you can avoid it, since neither one matches the current flexbox draft.

Comment: So do you recommend using the latest `display: flexbox`?

Comment: Well, I might, if anyone supported it.  But no one really does yet, last I checked, though Gecko and WebKit are close.

Comment: Thank you, will settle for "close" :). I just found [this article](http://css-tricks.com/old-flexbox-and-new-flexbox/), though, which says that `display: box` is the 2009 version of flexbox. How much can the new `flex` spec change at this point, being a CR?

Comment: The new spec is not expected to change much.  But it's also pretty different from that 2009 draft (which is what WebKit implements).